# Extract a selective list of entries from an Excel sheet using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

## How do I extract the x,y and z rows with the corresponding values in the "Value", "Value %" and "Upper Limit %" columns without including the rest of the contents?

### Current Python code being used

```
data = sheet_data.iloc[:,[0,1,2,4]]

data['Item Copy'] = data.loc[:,'Item'].ffill(axis=0)
actual_data = actual_data[actual_data['Category'].notna()]
actual_data = actual_data.loc[actual_data['Upper\nLimit %'].isnull()]
actual_data.reset_index(drop=True,inplace = True)

final_data = actual_data[~actual_data['Item'].notna()]
```

### Purpose of solution

Using Python with pandas and reading the entire sheet into a DataFrame. This process removes the formatting so indentation can't be used to selective get the values for x, y and z. This data needs to be extracted that the selected entries can be aggregated.

### Example content of Excel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you want to extract the contents of all cells from 'x' at the top left corner, down to the bottom right corner.

I'm not sure if your 'Current Python code being used' is initially reducing your spreadsheet down from a much larger file, or if it is attempting to make the extraction you describe—but I think it's the former.

Either way, given a file:

#### dataframe.tsv

```
column  Category    Value   Value % Upper Limit %
text    Sum of x,y,z    348753  9.18%
text    a   3895    1.61%
text    x   35735   1.53%
text    y   8375    6.04%
text    z   3895    1.61%
```

you can perform the extraction like this, which looks at the value of individual rows under `Category`, and retains only the desired rows for a specific set of columns:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Read in data; not needed if you already have it in memory
df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.tsv', sep = "\t")

# Set the values we want to retain
columns = ['Category', 'Value', 'Value %', 'Upper\nLimit %']
categories = ['x', 'y', 'z']

# Extract only the information we care about
subset = df[df['Category'].isin(categories)][columns]

# Reset index
subset.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
```

Comment: So the source data contains a lot more Categories ("Category a of a list of categories") and sub-categories ("Sum of x,y,z"). The current python code is being used to exclude the Category rows i.e. getting all the rows where Item and Upper Limit are _Nan_ .

Also there are a large number of rows and x,y,z aren't known, so there is no way to specify them the way you have done in the categories variable. So I'm trying to find an approach to exclude the sub-category entries in a similar way to how the Categories are excluded.

Comment: I see. If x, y, and z are actually unknown, and representative of a large number of rows you want to extract, can you clarify what the identifying traits of those rows is to someone (or a computer) who doesn't know about your categories and subcategories? Is it just that the 'Category' column value is indented in the Excel sheet? Or is there some convention in how that value is named (or not named) that could be used as a filter?

The question would be easier to answer if you provided an actual input file, show what your Python produces, the actual desired output, et cetera.